# How does 7-zip use threading?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, compression, 7zip

Is there an explanation on how multithreading in 7zip is implemented?

Does it compress several files in parallel, several blocks in parallel, or is the same block compressed by multiple threads?

And are there any trade-offs involving multithreading? For example, is the compressed file size affected?

Comment: It's just amazing how this question was closed. Who on Earth are you to consider this question unworthy of being asked ? 
And the answer is so lame "look at the code", why not RTFM ?

Comment: @cyan: This question is a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Perhaps it should have been migrated as opposed to closed out right. Either way it's not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Just for the record, I am quoting the FAQ: <Quote> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. <End Quote>. IMO My question was quite specific, but what the heck I will find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Comment: I have to agree that I don't see what was wrong with this question. I think it rather poor by all that voted for this to be closed as not a real question. It could have been stated more clearly, and some research shown. Still, it was a valid question.